# Rigid Body - Active objects pass thru my passive object's sides

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Just followed one of the simple 'Wrecking ball smashes cubes" tutorials.  My little cubes respect the 'floor' but not the side walls - the small cubes rest on the floor but slide right thru the walls.  Why would rigid body respect one part of my object 'floor' but not other part of the same object, 'walls'?  I even tried adding a solidify modifier to the object, but of course that didn't change anything, it's already solid.

I've removed and re-added rigid body to the floor object but it did not help.  Originally the floor was just a plane that I thickened by extruding and the side walls were extruded as well.  Does the rigid body sim still think the floor is a plane?

See image
[image]

Comment: I redid the floor with a cube,inset to make a box and now that problem is resolved.  Strange that it did not work with a plane extruded into the same basic shape.

Comment: "Convex hull" is not an appropriate collision shape for what you're showing, which is decidedly concave.  Divide it into multiple (convex) collider objects, or use mesh collision.